# Getting No Results For Search In php And mysqli

Tags: php, search, mysqli

I'm not getting why I dont get any results in this code, everytime I run it the else statement runs.

```
<?php 
            if(isset($_POST['search'])){
                    $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['user_query']);

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE search_title LIKE '%user_query%' OR search_desc LIKE '%user_query%' OR search_key LIKE '%user_query%' ";
            $run = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
            $queryResult = mysqli_num_rows($run);


        if($queryResult > 0){
            while($rel_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryResult)){
                echo "<div id='post'>
            <a href='#'><img src='$rel_rows[search_img]'></a>
            <a href='#'><h4 class='post_name'>$rel_rows[search_title]</h4></a>
            <p class='post_info'> $rel_rows[search_desc]</p>
        </div>";
            }
        }
        else{

            echo "There are no results for your search";
        }

            }
         ?>
```

Comment: `user_query` is not defined. Using full text indexing would be better. You also should parameterize the query.

Comment: It's actually searching for the text `user_query` in your string as it's hard coded.

Answer (score 0):

You passing the wrong search string;

Change to:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE search_title LIKE '%$search%' OR search_desc LIKE '%$search%' OR search_key LIKE '%$search%' ";
```

You are passing the wrong variable as parameter in mysqli_fetch_assoc(..)

Change to:

```
mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
  <?php 
                if(isset($_POST['search'])){
                        $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['user_query']);
$user_query=$search; 
//Added this line and replace user_query to $user_query in SQL query statement    
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE search_title LIKE '%$user_query%' OR search_desc LIKE '%$user_query%' OR search_key LIKE '%$user_query%' ";
                $run = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
                $queryResult = mysqli_num_rows($run);


            if($queryResult > 0){
                while($rel_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){
                    echo "<div id='post'>
                <a href='#'><img src='$rel_rows[search_img]'></a>
                <a href='#'><h4 class='post_name'>$rel_rows[search_title]</h4></a>
                <p class='post_info'> $rel_rows[search_desc]</p>
            </div>";
                }
            }
            else{

                echo "There are no results for your search";
            }

                }
             ?>
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: It would be useful to have some explanation of what you've done and how it would solve OP's problem.